# What is X in this operation?

Tags: assembly, avr

What is `X` in the following operation?

```
ldiw    X, RAMTOP
```

`ldiw` is defined as macro, taking 2 params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shorthand for a 16 bit register formed by two of the base registers:

> X,Y,Z: Indirect Address Register
>
> (X=R27:R26, Y=R29:R28 and Z=R31:R30)